# why is PullToRefresh moving ugly?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRJ64.gif)

I have Integrated PullToRefresh in an application. But when I use PullToRefreshListView to pull up refresh, it moved in a deformed manner. The ProgressBar went straight to the place which is next to the last item that in ListView.

Comment: Are u using a third party library  ?

Comment: Use the list view below pull to refresh

Comment: yes，i used the "chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout instead of PullToRefreshListView.

Comment: thanks , but i‘ve written a lot used it.is there any other way to do it?

Comment: you need to edit library codes. But I think it's worth to refactor codes for replacing   PullToRefreshListView with SwipeRefreshLayout